# AWS - How to extract CSV reports from a set of JSON files in S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a RDS database with the following structure: `CustomerId|Date|FileKey`.
FileKey points to a JSON file in S3.

Now I want to create CSV reports with a costumer, date range filters and columns definition (ColumnName + JsonPath), like that:

```
Name => data.person.name
OtherColumn1 => data.exampleList[0]
OtherColumn2 => data.exampleList[2]
```

I often need to add and remove columns from the columns definition.

I know I can run a SQL SELECT on RDS, get each S3 file (JSON), extract the data and create my CSV file, but, this is not a good solution because I need to query my RDS instance and make millions of requests to S3 for each report request or each columns definition change.

Saving all data on RDS table instead on S3 is also not a good solution because JSON file contains a lot of data and columns not the same for costumers.

Any idea?

Comment: how long it will take to generate report file from json ? if it is below 15 mins then you can take advantage of lambda and process json file and convert to csv. lambda is cheaper as compared to RDS storing and querying data.

Comment: @Prashant time depends on date range. I want limit the date rante, so, I think the maximum number of rows for one report request will be 1 million. And yes, I can develop a code to query my RDS instance (SELECT FileKey .. WHERE Date BETWEEN...) and get each JSON file on S3 to create the CSV rows, storing my code on Lambda or EC2 instance, but, I think there are other AWS features to do this. And the next step (after creating my simple CSV report) is performing more complex data analysis.

Comment: i think your use case is for S3 Select service.